# Cisco nexus C93180YC-EX sflow configuration

Tags: cisco, switch, network, sflow

I am running cisco nexus C93180YC-EX switch and I would like to enable sflow for collector. I did similar config on 9396PX model and it works but Nexus 93180 is little different. I am running NXOS 9.3.10 version

TCAM size is zero for sflow

```
# show run all | grep tcam | grep sflow
hardware access-list tcam region sflow 0 
hardware access-list tcam region span-sflow 0
```

I tried to reduce size of span tcam from 512 to 256 to give slice to sflow but I found there is no option to give tcam size to sflow. what I am missing here?

```
(config)# hardware access-list tcam region sflow 256
                                 ^
% Invalid command at '' marker.
(config)#
```

Cisco [sflow](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/dcn/nx-os/nexus9000/103x/configuration/system-management/cisco-nexus-9000-series-nx-os-system-management-configuration-guide-103x/m-configuring-sflow-10x.pdf) Reference do is here but didn't mention that it required TCAM for 93180YC-EC hardware required any carving or tcam. does that mean I can just configure without TCAM?

Comment: Have you tried? ;-)

Comment: I can try for sure but before that just wanted to confirm with someone who already did that. I am little nervous before turn it on just incase if it start chewing up all my CPU without tcam support.

Comment: File a bug with TAC. "sho run all" should not be showing anything that isn't a valid configuration.

Comment: Will do that to TAC

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

I just setup sflow (without tcam carving) on production switch and it works. I can see flows on my collector.

```
feature sflow

sflow counter-poll-interval 30
sflow collector-ip 10.0.8.72 vrf management
sflow agent-ip 10.0.8.16

sflow data-source interface Ethernet1/49
```

I have noticed very small CPU spike on graph but that is not concerning.

```
# show sflow statistics
Total Packets        : 20395826099159    Packets
Total Samples        : 7918590990    Bytes
Processed Samples    : 56083451    Packets
Rate-Limiter Drops   : 0    Bytes
Dropped sflow Samples: 0    Packets
Sent Datagrams       : 7620468    Packets
Dropped Datagrams    : 10    Packets
```

This is one more place to keep eyes.

```
# show hardware rate-limiter

Units for Config: kilo bits per second
Allowed, Dropped & Total: aggregated bytes since last clear counters


Module: 1
  R-L Class             Config              Allowed              Dropped                Total
 +----------------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
  L3 glean                 100              4216430                    0              4216430
  L3 mcast loc-grp        3000                    0                    0                    0
  access-list-log          100                    0                    0                    0
  bfd                    10000                    0                    0                    0
  fex                    12000                    0                    0                    0
  span                      50                    0                    0                    0
  sflow                  40000           7880134731                    0           7880134731
  vxlan-oam               1000                    0                    0                    0
  100M-ethports          10000                    0                    0                    0
  span-egress         disabled                    0                    0                    0
  dot1x                   3000                    0                    0                    0
  mpls-oam                 300                    0                    0                    0
  netflow               120000                    0                    0                    0
  ucs-mgmt               12000                    0                    0                    0
```